# How to interactively add files in Perforce (equivalent of `git add -p`)

Tags: git, perforce

Is there something in Perforce that works like `git add -p`?

I'd like to diff my local file against the depot, and then choose which parts of the diff will end up in the changelist.

(My goal here is to take multiple changes I've made to a file and commit them in two separate changelists, since they're not conceptually related. But you could also use this to not commit debug code but still leave it in locally).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You'll need to shelve one set of changes first.

Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Perforce does not have git's concept of a staging area, so an equivalent of `git add -p` doesn't really make sense (where do you want the non-added edits to go?  Into a shelved change?)

Personally I use `git-p4` and to create a git mirror of a Perforce tree, and then I can actually use `git add -p`. (You alternatively might want to look into Perforce's Git Fusion system.)

Comment: git-p4 sounds pretty great!

>where do you want the non-added edits to go? Into a shelved change?

That's essentially what I ended up doing manually, so sure. (Although I managed to screw something up and lose them)